# How to get Android Studio gradle to execute pre-build step

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I want to scale a bunch of vector images into a range of sensible PNG images for different resolutions, but for some reason Gradle doesn't find my tasks that I am adding. It doesn't print any error messages, and says build successful, but it doesn't run the task either. My gradle file (the one from the app dir, not the other weird one from the directory above - dunno why I need so many gradle files but nevermind)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    task compileAssets(type: Exec, description: 'Compile Assets') {
        commandLine 'inkscape.exe', '-z -e app\\src\\main\\assets\\bkgd_1080_1920.png -w 1080 -h 1920 ..\\AssetsSrc\\Layout_16_9.svg'    
    }

    preBuild.dependsOn compileAssets

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nocompany.hr"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using AndroidStudio 1.5.1 / Gradle 2.8.

I have code that I need to execute before the build and this works for me:

```
android {

    ... 

    preBuild << {
        // PUT CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: build.gradle in the app directory (the one in the question).